# Why is this unity code to stop velocity not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm quite new to unity, and I used this code to move the character while D is held down and reset horizontal velocity to 0 to prevent sliding. It worked fine before I added the else if but now it won't move at all.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (0,0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rigidbody ? is the name of the class, not the instance.. or did you just name it bad

Comment: I did just name it badly at the top of the class I put `public Rigidbody Rigidbody;` and dragged the gameobject's rigidbody onto the script

Comment: and what happened when you debugged it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use velocity I would use position that removes sliding completely:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + transform.position.x, transform.position.y,0);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.velocity = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you seem to be using `Rigidbody` when you should be using `Rigidbody2D`. You didn't clarify what version of Unity you are using but it seems like it's the 2D one. Using the wrong Rigidbody class could cause all sorts of unexpected behavior.

If that doesn't solve it the next obvious thing would be debugging. If the problem only emerged with the if-else, I would first check if its condition is properly met. maybe your program has some problem with the GetKeyUp function. Just check the 'if' is true when it should be, and print a simple message whenever it's true.

If the problem isn't there then it must be with the `Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (0,0);` line. perhaps there is another code affecting the velocity at the same time. Maybe gravity is set to an unusual scale and setting the vertical velocity to 0 causes unexpected behavior.

I'm fairly certain doing all of this will 100% solve your problem.

I Hope I Helped, Goodluck(;

Comment: `You didn't clarify what version of Unity you are using but it seems like it's the 2D one.` .. there is no specific 2D version of Unity ;) There is 2D components for the 2D physics engine and a front view that results in a 2D app

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, I guess you're right, still what I said about using Rigidbody when one should use RigidBody2D stands. Anyway, there's already an accepted answer now that was a whole different approach so I guess it's a moot point now. Cheers ;)